# Construct Excel Date and Hour

Tags: excel, date, text

I have a date in text form that excel is not recognizing as a date and hour like i want it to. Is there a formula to break down this text and then build it back up as the correct date and time?

01.01.2012 08:00:00.000

Comment: How would January 13th 2012 be formatted? The example is ambiguous as we don't know if it shows dd.mm.yyyy (as in the UK and elsewhere) or mm.dd.yyyy (as in the US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=DATE(MID(C5,7,4),MID(C5,4,2),LEFT(C5,2)) + TIME(MID(C5,12,2),MID(C5,15,2),MID(C5,18,2))`

When the date string is in cell C5